# MSSQL запрос в Django ORM

Tags: python, django

Есть запрос:

```sql
declare @cnt_day int = 2

select top (1) with ties [t1].[rid]
                       , [t1].[name_obj]
                       , [t1].[date_time]
from [table1] as [t1]
where isnull([t1].[tyev], 0) = 0
      and convert(date, [t1].[date_time]) >= (convert(date, getdate() - @cnt_day))
order by row_number() over( partition by [t1].[name_obj]
                            order by [t1].[date_time] desc)
```

Как его можно записать для ORM Django?
Или необходимо менять конструкцию запроса?

Переписал запрос, но уперся в проблему с датами.

```sql
select [t1].[rid]
     , [t1].[name_obj]
     , [t1].[date_time]
from [table1] as [t1]
     inner join ( select max([rid]) as [rid]
                  from [table1]
                  where isnull([tyev], 0) = 0
                        and cast([date_time] as date) >= cast(getdate() - 1 as date)
                  group by [name_obj] ) as [t2]
             on([t1].[rid] = [t2].[rid])
```

```py
days = request.POST['days'] # Введенное кол-во дней например 1
now = datetime.date.today() # Пусть будет 20190604
dd = now - datetime.timedelta(days = int(days)) # 2019-06-04 - 1 = 2019-06-03
journal_data = table1.objects.filter(Q(tyev=0) | Q(tyev__isnull=True),date_time__gte = dd)
```

при выполнении данного кода, выдает странные результаты:

```py
print(''+str(dd)) # Все ок, получаю 2019-06-03
```

но вот формируемый sql скрипт получается следующий:

```sql
select [table1].[rid]
     , [table1].[name_obj]
     , [table1].[date_time]
from [table1]
where(([table1].[tyev] = 0
       or [table1].[tyev] is null)
      and [table1].[date_time] >= '2019-06-02 13:00:00')
```

как видно, дата получена странная - 2 дня, да и время взялось не понимаю откуда.

Comment: Django умеет выполнять "сырой" SQL (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/).

Comment: @Akina Хотелось бы обойтись без этого, если возможно.